# Regex to replace a word by starting sub String and ends with dot or space in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace #id in my css String, let say I have id as #id_123456 as id in my css I have to replace it with #id_7891011. I know my id starts with #id_ and it can end with ./space/+/>.
I am trying to do regex to replace all my old id with new Id. My regex looks like.

```
(.* ?)(#id_[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[.^\S])(.*)
```

It working for the start condition but not end by the space or dot it replaces the whole line.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `./space/+/>` ? Using `\S` will also match a dot or caret.

Comment: Using `(.*? )` and `(.*)` will select the whole line. If it should end with a dot or space, then use `#id_[a-zA-Z0-9]+[. ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead:

```
#id_[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?=[.\s+>])
                  |_________|
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wRXVCI/1). The `(?=[.\s+>])` will make sure matching stops before `.`/whitespace/`+`/`>`.

Comment: Thank you @Ryszard Czech. It works perfectly except I just removed /s after 0-9 as it is ignoring the space.

Comment: @Jagan You are welcome. Feel free to edit the expression to meet your needs.

Comment: I suggest `(?=[. +>])` in place of `(?=[.\s+>])` to avoid matching `#id_123456\n>`. I've seen many-a-question that refers to a "space" where a whitespace has been used to match it in a suggested regex. In some cases that has resulted in inadvertent matches of a newline. I see no reason to use `\s` to match a space.